# Sending data from Arduino to Java Program via Bluetooth

Tags: java, bluetooth, arduino

I am working on a project where I am trying to get information from an Arduino Pro Mini to a Java Program on my computer via Bluetooth.

I have the Arduino end working, and I am able to connect to the bluetooth module on the Arduino with my computer and get the data to be printed out with CoolTerm.

My problem is getting the Java Program to read from the bluetooth connection that my computer has with the bluetooth module on the Arduino Pro Mini.

I have only been able to find solutions when developing an Android App. THIS IS NOT AN ANDROID PROJECT, I do not want android solutions.

Does anyone have an example of how to utilize a bluetooth connection on your computer with a Java Program (not android) so that I can read the information, the Arduino Pro Mini is sending to my computer, through my java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [nrjavaserial](https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial) in my code.  I'm running on Linux with a little USB Bluetooth adapter and it has worked well.  In your code you'll do something like:

```
NRSerialPort serial = new NRSerialPort("/dev/rfcomm0", 115200);
serial.connect();

DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(serial.getInputStream());
```

The hard part is the device name.  Ubuntu has a nice Bluetooth setup where I can pair and connect the device to a serial port.  I've not done this on other O/S's though.

Note that nrjavaserial includes native libraries that use JNI under the covers.

Comment: I will try that out! Thanks

Comment: What is the first parameter in NRSerialPort? Is that suppose to be the name of the device? And I take it the second parameter is the Baud Rate.